# How do I play and publish my custom map?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Three questions which would raise long answers:

1. If I create my own map, how do I play it?  Do I need a dedicated server?
2. How can I register my map on the Steam Workshop?
3. Are all maps accepted on the Steam Workshop?

Comment: For number 1, you just want to test it out? Just hit F9 in Hammer to test it.

Comment: yeah, testing goes ok. I just want to play it with my friends online.

Comment: Make sure you don't make a real life subway map or something like that, especially if you live in Canada :P.

Answer (score 1):

I'll get questions 2 and 3 out of the way first.  In the CS:GO authoring tools, open the Workshop Map Publisher.  This is where you input all your information about your map, including name, a short description, and what game mode.  As soon as you click publish, your map will be on the workshop, give or take some Valve Time.

**Before you do any hosting, you'll need to forward ports in your router.**  [Find your router in this list](http://portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/Counter-Strike_-_Global_Offensive/default.htm), and you will be guided on how to forward the ports needed for CS:GO.

I would highly recommend starting listen server, a server hosted while you're playing CS:GO and will be shutdown when you disconnect, rather than a dedicated server.  Dedicated servers are used only if you're going to be hosting for a very long time.

- First, place your completed map in %steamapps%\common\CS:GO\csgo\maps\
- Then, [go to this website](http://whatismyip.com), and jot down your IP address.  You'll give this out to your friends.
- Now, start CS:GO, and open the console with the tilde key, <kbd>`</kbd>, then type `map your_map_name` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Once your map loads, open the console again, and input `sv_lan 0`, this will allow other players to join.
- That's it!  Other players will be able to join with the console command `connect your.ip.here`.  Just make sure they've downloaded your map from the workshop before they connect.

NB: If players cannot connect to your server, open the Steam Overlay, head over to [CanYouSeeMe.org](http://canyouseeme.org), and enter port 27015.  If this test fails, players will not be able to connect; make sure all your ports are forwarded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. No if you upload the map to the workshop you should just be able to play it in an offline game with bots or custom lobby with friends.
2. If you are doing it for CS-GO then you need to go to the CS-GO main menu and in the command prompt type "workshop_publish" and follow the steps that it gives you
3. Yes all maps are accepted on the workshop

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was answered twice I will still share my knowledge. First off you do not need a server (community servers are a whole different topic). Depending on your account privileges, your map can be viewed by anyone. To get to the workshop publisher you will first need to enter steam. Be sure you have the developer console enabled (do so in game settings). in the console (opened using the <kbd>`</kbd> key) type in `workshop_publish`. Make sure your rendered map is in the proper map folder, this is for windows users.

```
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\maps)
```

You can choose the map and then upload using the desired settings. Every map is accepted but they can be taken down if they aren't working properly or extremely poorly made.